# Multiple UPDATE's in a single query

Tags: mysql

In a database of mine, there is a couple of indexes that got updated and to save a year worth of data I need to rearange these indexes.

So, I have a table called `FloatTableOld` that has a field that needs to be updated called `TagIndex`.

I also have the old indexes that are stored in `TagTableOld` and the new ones are stored in `TagTable`, that share the field `TagName`, and I need to replace `TagTableOld`.`TagIndex` with `TagTable`.`TagIndex`.

I'm having a bit of trouble because I want to do this in a single query. What I've got is:

```
UPDATE `FloatTableOld` 
SET `FloatTableOld`.`TagIndex` = 
(
    SELECT `relacao`.`newTag` FROM
    (
        SELECT  `TagTable`.`TagName`,
            `TagTableOld`.`TagIndex` AS `oldTag`,
            `TagTable`.`TagIndex` AS `newTag`
        FROM `TagTable`
        INNER JOIN `TagTableOld`
        ON `TagTable`.`TagName` = `TagTableOld`.`TagName`
    ) AS `relacao`
    WHERE `FloatTableOld`.`TagName` = `relacao`.`oldTag`
)
WHERE `FloatTableOld`.`TagIndex` = 
(
    SELECT `FloatTableOld`.`TagIndex` 
    FROM `FloatTableOld`
)
```

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'FloatTableOld' for update in FROM clause
```

Can anyone help me with this? Can't really understand the error.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `update` with `join` for this.  If I understand correctly:

```
update floattableold fto join
       tagtableold tto
       on fto.tagindex = tto.tagindex join
       tagtable tt
       on tt.tagname = tto.tagname
    set fto.tagindex = tt.tagindex;
```

Comment: This is a much simpler and easier aproach than what I was thinking. Works really well. Cheers!